# Can't Get Ubuntu 18.04 To Install Alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, uefi, windows-10

I seem to be having trouble getting Ubuntu 18.04 to install on my Windows 10 system. My laptop is an MSI GE72 Apache Pro 6QD with two drives, a primary SDD where I have Windows installed, and a HDD where I'd like to install Ubuntu. Previously I had been able to get past the GRUB and into the Ubuntu desktop where I was able to select 'Install', but it always froze around the partitioning phase, and now I am unable to get past the Ubuntu loading screen at all. The first few dots light up but it hangs on the last dot.

Here are things I've tried already:

- downloaded torrent of "ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" and verified checksum
- disabled hibernation, pagefile, system protection
- defragged using stock defrag and Piriform Defraggler
- compressed hard drives
- shrunk HDD as far as I could to create 60GB unallocated space for Ubuntu
- downloaded Rufus and configured USB thumb drive for GPT partition style

Here are settings within my UEFI:

- updated MSI UEFI to latest version
- disabled Secure Boot
- disabled Fast Boot
- boot mode: UEFI

Is there something I'm missing? Really excited to try out Ubuntu and learn more about this community but I can't seem to get in!

Thanks to all.

Comment: Did you choose install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Comment: I did at first, and got as far as the screen where you can select the size of the partition with the slider, then it froze. Now I cannot get past the Ubuntu loading screen.

Comment: Install Ubuntu alongside Windows option comes before partitioning.

Comment: So yes, I initially was able to get to the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option and then proceeded to the partitioning phase where the installation froze. Now when I attempt to select either options "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" from the GRUB it takes me to a loading screen with the Ubuntu logo and several horizontal dots, all of which except the last light up, and the process hangs indefinitely.

Comment: This question is very old, but I hope this might help: Just before booting from the USB, on the menu, select “Install Ubuntu” and press “e”, then on the line that reads “linux /cas/vmlinuz”, just before the “quiet splash — -”, write “nomodeset”, then press “F10” to run.

Comment: Thanks very much!